# It is possible to get cookies from a flash application using java?

Tags: java, flash, cookies

I'm trying to get data from a website, but first I need to log in to the site using java. The script worked until now, but now the site installed an anti bot system. Until now the procedure was simple, I've created a HttpStreamWriter and submitted my details to the login.php page, then get the cookies and later, when I want to get data from the site, I resubmit the cookie from the login.php page, but now there is a problem: an anti bot system:
I'm not sure, but I think this is the system:
https://github.com/yuri-gushin/Roboo/blob/master/Roboo.pm

The anti bot system creates a cookie, called anti-bot and I can't access the page without that cookie, the problem is that the cookie is generated by a flash application only after the page loads so I can't get the cookie from the page?

Any ideas how to "hack" this ? Thanks!

Comment: Please note the difference between single quote (') and grave accent(`)  You should always use single quotes for apostrophes, because the grave accent is used by SO to format text as code. You'll also be able to type a lot faster, because there's no need to push the space bar to get the character to appear properly.

Comment: You could contact the people responsible for the website and ask if they support any method for getting the data that you want. If they don't, and have put the "anti bot system" you mention in place to stop people from doing what you are trying to do, then maybe you should consider respecting that?

Answer (score 0):

Your need is about cookie extraction, here is [how to do](http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html) or on the [oracle site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/cookie_support.html)

That is you need to connect to the site, browse the headers until `Set-Cookie`. Having the correct http header, you'll be able to parse it very easily.

After what, you'll have to set it back to your further request.

## Edit

Flash cookie or [Local Shared Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_shared_object) are stored in AMF. AMF wil be used store anything, the problem with your use case is that you don't know which value (or maybe class instances) have been serialized...

However you could (it will take time, at least for include all necessary libs) try with the [AMFConnection](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/Java+AMF+Client) to retrieve information. But I won't bet on that.

Could you contact the webmaster to have some information about that ? Or doens't this website any login api ?

Comment: I did this with the normal php page, but now I need to do this with a flash application, and I don`t know how to connect to a flash application that also have some parameters too